# How to solve the TAlib giving incorrect result when input contains nans

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, ta-lib

I have a 2-D array which contains lots of nans. Each column has 244 not nan float number when calculating the MA of each column, the function gives the correct result

```py
`np.sum(~np.isnan(talib.MA(b[:,0],5)))`
`Out[106]: 240`
`np.sum(~np.isnan(talib.MA(b[:,1],5)))`
`Out[107]: 240`
```

However,when flatten the 2D array into a 1D array, the MA function's output only has 240 not nan data. After checking the result I found it lost the result of the second column.

```py
`np.sum(~np.isnan(talib.MA(b.flatten(order = 'F'),5)))`
`Out[108]: 240`
```

Are there some solutions to fix this problem, besides, does the talib function supports using 2d arrays directly?

Acutually, I found that talib wont calculate the value after it the nans except in the begining.

eg.

```py
f = np.array([nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nan, nan, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
f2 = talib.MA(f,2)
```

will have a result like

```py
f2 array([nan, nan, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,nan])
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

TA-Lib is a library written in C which you access via python [wrapper](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) made by John Benediktsson. The C library doesn't support 2d arrays at all. The python wrapper can accept such arrays if only C-library function expects OHLC-like input. In this case it will interpret columns named "open", "high", "low", "close" etc as corresponding input data. No any 2d arrays support in a way you expects. Please refer to wrapper's documentation ans samples.

TA-Lib doesn't expect any NANs in input and you should never pass them to it. Any operation with NAN will result to NAN and you'll get incorrect results.

The first NANs in output from your example have nothing with NANs in input. They are result of timeperiod=2 you passed in MA constructor. Moving Averages can't be calculated for every input value, they have a warm up period. C-library return nothing for this period and just reply the data index from which it was able to provide the result. So its result is shorter than input array in this case. Python wrapper inserts NANs into C-Library reply to make output the same size as input.

Comment: great reply! Too bad it cannot ignore NaN's.